# Filter JSON datasource with Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, filtering, dropdownbox

I need to populate Kendo drop-down box automatically from the following JSON:

```
var products=
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Item-1",
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Item-2",
        active: false
    }
];
```

So I use the following code to do this, which works fine:

```
$("#productList").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: products,
    dataTextField: "title",
    dataValueField: "id"
});
```

The problem is, I want to see only items for which 'active' is true.

How to implement that with Kendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R778c/4/)

For Filter, can only be filter on **dataSoruce** that why creating **kendo.data.DataSource** and apply filter in **filter** section.

> **filter:{*fieled*:"active",*operator*:"eq",*value*:true}**

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input id="productList" style="width:250px"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var products=
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Item-1",
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Item-2",
        active: undefined
    },
    {
        id:3,
        title:"Item-3",
        active:false
    },
    {
        id:3,
        title:"Item-4",
        active:undefined
    }
];
var dataSource=new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data:products,
   filter:{
       logic:'or',
       filters:[
           {field:"active",operator:"eq",value:true},
           {field:"active",operator:"eq",value:undefined}
       ]}
});

$("#productList").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    dataTextField: "title",
    dataValueField: "id"
});
```

Comment: Nice answer, and it works, thank you! And what if I want to change the condition to this one: <if active is true or undefined>, to support a default value. How to change the filter for this?

Comment: @user1102051 , already updated with multi filter options in dataSource